# supervisor: can't start/restart

Tags: python, celery, supervisord

### Enviroment

- supervisor:4.1.0
- Python:3.6.9

### Status

I am trying to daemonize a celery process with a supervisor.
The configuration files are as follows.
`/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

`/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celeryd.conf`

```
[program:celeryd]
user=user_name
directory=/home/user_name/my_app/api/
command=celery -A v2 worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 --maxtasksperchild=5000 -Q=celery
environment=MY_APP_DEPLOY_CONFIG=production
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

### Problem

When trying to start a process, the following error occurs.

```
$ sudo supervisorctl restart all
celeryd: ERROR (no such file)

$ sudo supervisorctl start all
celeryd: ERROR (no such file)

$ sudo supervisorctl status
celeryd                          FATAL     can't find command 'celery'
```

The strange thing is that if I edit the conf file and do a `supervisor reread`, it works fine

```
$ sudo supervisorctl reread
celeryd: changed
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

if you use virtualenv you should specify full path to celery in command

```
command = /full_path_to_celery/celery -A v2 worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 --maxtasksperchild=5000 -Q=celery
```

also you maybe from you user system can't celery, you can easily check it by auth using your user and type `which celery` if it outputs path you have an access to it.

Comment: I don't use virtualenv.celery full path is here -> `/usr/local/bin/celery`

Comment: You can try to specify it in command and see what will happen